# Word for being the only one to volunteer

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe a person or action where out of a group of people, there is a single volunteer to undergo a task or similar.

This is due to the task being somewhat undesirable, and there is only a single person willing to undergo it. For example:

> Scipio Africanus ______ to lead the Roman troops against the Carthaginian army in Spain.

Comment: "Stuckee" is the common term in many businesses.

Comment: They are *a* volunteer. To my knowledge there is no single word that specifically describes a volunteer that is also the *only* volunteer. The nearest would be "[they were the] only volunteer"

Comment: You should give more context. Is the person  somehow forced to be volunteer or is it just a personal  choice?

Comment: Not a single word but what about "sole volunteer" or "lone volunteer"?

Comment: In British English, the term 'muggins' is often used for someone who has foolishly taken on much more than their fair share of the work; it's usually used (as self-deprecation) in the first person: *"Muggins here has volunteered to put up the tent."* It suggests being a willing stooge.

Comment: @Josh61 I've added some clarification as well as an example

Answer (score 1):

[**sacrificial lamb**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacrificial_lamb), if properly phrased, in the reflexive, can express that:

> [Neotestamentica: Journal of the New Testament Society of ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=NVTlAAAAMAAJ&q=%22into%20a%20sacrificial%20lamb%22&dq=%22into%20a%20sacrificial%20lamb%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=q4UaVYDXHsqoNv34gdAB&redir_esc=y) 2004
>
> The violence and death which he suffered is transformed into a gift to
>   God, and an act of love for his followers. The blood of the Lamb is
>   that of the foundational martyr, of **the shepherd who has made
>   himself into a sacrificial lamb** for his sheep.

Answer (score 1):

If Bob decides to assume responsibility for something, we can say that bob has [**taken it upon himself**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/take-it-upon-yourself-to-do-something). This isn't exactly the same meaning requested, but it's the closest idiom I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

"He **dedicated himself** to lead the troops ..."

> Definition of "dedication": self-sacrificing devotion